# CouchDB sorting - Collation Specification

Tags: couchdb

Collation Specification

Using a CouchDB view it seems my keys aren't sorted as per the collation specification.

```
rows:
   [0] key: ["bylatest", -1294536544000] value: 1         
   [1] key: ["bylatest", -1298817134000] value: 1
   [2] key: ["bylatest", -1294505612000] value: 1
```

I would of expect the second entry to come after the third.

Why is this happening?

Comment: CouchDB team have acknowledged this bug seem to affect big num sorting as /1000 works.Okay back to work.. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1267

Comment: The bug appears to be in enif_compare, part of Erlang itself. We are awaiting confirmation from the OTP team. A short-term fix is to disable ejson. I'll also note that this issue only affects trunk, not any official CouchDB release.

Answer (score 0):

I get this result for a view emitting the values you indicate.

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"29e86c6bf38b9068c56ab1cd0100101f","key":["bylatest",-1298817134000],"value":1},
{"id":"29e86c6bf38b9068c56ab1cd0100101f","key":["bylatest",-1294536544000],"value":1},
{"id":"29e86c6bf38b9068c56ab1cd0100101f","key":["bylatest",-1294505612000],"value":1}
]}
```

The rows are different from *both* of your examples. They fit the collation specification by beginning with the smallest (greatest magnitude negative) value and ending with the greatest value (least magnitude negative in this case).

Would you perhaps include the documents and map/reduce functions you are using?

Comment: This is only broken on trunk (ejson is new).